# How to run a script with correct permissions from custom udev rule?

Tags: bash, unix, ubuntu-18.04, udev

I set up a custom udev rule triggered when my bluetooth mouse connects:

```
ACTION=="add" \
, ATTRS{idProduct}=="XXX" \
, ATTRS{idVendor}=="XXX" \
, ENV{DISPLAY}=":0" \
, ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority" \
, RUN+="/home/XXX/.scripts/mouse_connected.sh"
```

udevadm test succeeds, everything seems fine.
Then i created my script that should be triggered:

```
#!/bin/bash  
if (xinput list | grep Maus | grep -o id=[0-9]* | grep -o [0-9]*$); 
        then xinput set-button-map "$(xinput list | grep Maus | grep -o id=[0-9]* | grep -o [0-9]*$)" 1 1 3 && logger "success";  
        else logger "fail" && sleep 3;
fi
```

when I manually run the script in terminal using "bash '/home/XXX/.scripts/mouse_connected.sh'" it works as expected. But when it gets successfully triggered via my custom udev rule it fails. - But why?

Comment: `xinput` needs `XDISPLAY`. It needs access to your x server. add `export XDISPLAY=:0.0` to your script and also add `xhost +` to allow root access on the xserver as the user that is logged in on the xserver. Try this: run your script from CTRL+ALT+F1 terminal, without graphics.

Comment: I didn't succeed. My script still fails when triggered by rule and works when triggered manually. (I didn't understand your suggestion with CTRL+ALT+F1 terminal) This is my updated script:

`#!/bin/bash

export XDISPLAY=:0.0
xhost +

if (xinput list | grep Maus | grep -o id=[0-9]* | grep -o [0-9]*$); 
        then xinput set-button-map "$(xinput list | grep Maus | grep -o id=[0-9]* | grep -o [0-9]*$)" 1 1 3 && logger "success";  
        else logger "fail" && sleep 3;
fi`

Comment: Don't add `xhost +` to your script, run `xhost +` from Xserver before connecting. And did you run the script without the graphical interface?

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow your instructions. Where should I insert "xhost +"? And isn't that pretty unsafe? And as mentioned above, I didn't understand how run the script without graphic interface. CTRL+ALT+F1 gets me to login screen with no terminal, after logging in I'm back where I was before.

Comment: `isn't that pretty unsafe` - not unless you have XDMCP or other X forwarding option enabled and no firewall installed. For safety you can do `xhost +localhost`, for testing `xhost +` is better. To connect from root (or any other non-X place) to your xserver, you need to: Tell the program where to find that xserver (the `export DISPLAY=:0.0` line, tells to search for xserver on localhost sequence number 0 display number 0) and you need to allow your xserver to accept connections (the `xhost +` line allows all connections).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still don't know where I should put `xhost +`? I added the line `, RUN+="xhost +" \ ` to my udev-rule, but that got me the error `Process 'xhost +' failed with exit code 2.`